# Modifying CURRENT_TIMESTAMP per Firebird database

Tags: timestamp, firebird, firebird2.5, symmetricds

I have many databases on the same server, representing different time zones in each one (pacific, mountain, central and eastern). Right now my programs use things like `'NOW'` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to get the current time for the records. This is a problem.

The data is being synchronized from separate computers to this central server using SymmetricDS. However, I'm having the problem that the programs being run at this central server are written as if they were local to the office. This means that when it calls for timestamps, it does it at the time zone of the server that may not represent their office. Certain data continuity is being jumbled as a result.

Aside from going through the programs and rewriting every situation that utilizes the current time, we would much rather find a way to represent time differently in each database... somehow offsetting the timezone in each database separately.

Having done as much reading as I can find relevant to this topic, what are my options?

Comment: If you  know the time zone  you can store it in database and can use `dateadd(hour,-cast(:tz_hour as integer),current_timestamp);`

Comment: The dilemma is that we want to alter all of the time related functions and context variables in Firebird to do this for us. We have a huge body of code, and replacing it everywhere would take a significant amount of time :\

Comment: Unfortunately there is no real option, except maybe make your server run in UTC, so all systems at least use the same date (but that could still wreck havoc if clients are inserting times or timestamp in the local timezone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create a procedure for this task.
 
First of all you could start with a new table. Let's use the following structure: [image: Basic office database]

Moreover let's create the following stored procedure:

```
create or alter procedure GETTIMESTAMP (
    IOFFICE_ID bigint)
returns (
    RTIMESTAMP timestamp)
as
begin
  RTIMESTAMP=dateadd(hour,coalesce((select TIMEDIFF from OFFICE_TIMEZONE where OFFICE_ID_=:IOFFICE_ID),0), current_timestamp);
  suspend;
end
```

This procedure will return the correct time. If the office does not exsits, it will return the current_timestamp of the local server. 
Of course it takes some work to get this into your database. To make it easy you could search in your database metadata. IBExpert features a simple search dialog, but you could also export your meta data and search via notepad.[image: IBExpert search in metadata]